# Pytest import problems when tests import from adjacent directory

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-import

```
/root
|- __init__.py
|
|- /src 
|  |
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- /x
|     |
|     |- __init__.py
|     |- xy.py
|
|- /tests
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- /test_x
|     |
|     |- __init__.py
|     |- test_xy.py
```

```
# tests/test_x/test_xy.py 

from src.x.xy import XY

Class TestXY:

    # etc
```

When I’m in root I try to run `pytest tests/*/*` and I get an error that due to `from src.x.xy import XY` because `src` can’t be found. If I change the import to `from …src.x.xy import XY` I get “cannot import” because it’s from a directory one level above.

I also tried running `Python -m pytest tests/*/*` but I get an error about conftest not being found in `__pycache__` which I don’t understand. `(ERROR: not found: /root/tests/__pycache__/conftest.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.2.pyc (no name '/root/tests/__pycache__/conftest.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.2.pyc' in any of []))`

What am I missing? Why is it so hard to run tests this way? I can run them individually in pycharm by clicking the little green arrows in the test script no problem.

Answer (score 1):

In that architecture of project you should use config file. Config file should have path to src.

`pyproject.toml` example:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "src"
]
```

`pytest.ini` example:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = src
```

If you will have multiple src directories you also can add it to config

For example `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "src", "src2",
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Where should these files go?

Comment: Nvm -- putting both in root worked (do I need both)? I had to run it with `python -m pytest tests/` not `tests/*/*`

Comment: No, just one. `.ini` or `.toml`

Comment: TOML worked for me. 
I am perplexed that it is necessary, the src/tests structure felt logical but apparently that's non-standard...
Thanks Pavel!